# Logon script causes powershell.exe to launch and close in a loop

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo

I created a logon script that promotes any user that has been on the machine in the last X days to the Administrators group.  I have tested this script successfully and have no issues with execution in any of my tests.  I created a GPO that links this script to a particular OU in my org and I'm finding something like a 25% failure rate to properly execute.

The "failure" is the troublesome part because 1) its only occurs for a relatively small number of users, and because of this 2) I don't understand what is happening conceptually.  Specifically the user gets signed in, and then PowerShell.exe launches and closes immediately, but then continues to do this indefinitely until you force quit powershell - the window takes focus on the desktop and prevents users from working.

When I use Computer Management to remotely view the Administrator group membership on the computer I can see that the script ran successfully (it promotes the users to Admins) but I'm not sure what causes it to respawn, and only for some users.

I can post the script if it will help (its short) but since its "working" most of the time, I'd be inclined to assume some component of PowerShell is failed or failing on these machines.  I'm hoping this kind of behavior is a known, or has been experienced by someone in the community before.
The last point I'll add is that in 2 cases just having the user reboot fixed it.

Script Code:

```
# Launches elevated PS session if possible.
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}

$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

# Non-builtin regular user SIDs are always prefixed S-1-5-21-
$DomainUserFilter = "SID LIKE 'S-1-5-21-%'"

# Suppress Errors
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

# Retrieve user profiles
$DomainProfiles = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter $DomainUserFilter

foreach($UserProfile in $DomainProfiles)
{
  # Check if profile was ever used, skip if not
  if(-not $UserProfile.LastUseTime)
  {
    continue
  }

  # Convert the datetime string to a proper datetime object
  $LastUsed = $UserProfile.ConvertToDateTime($UserProfile.LastUseTime)

  # Compare against threshold
  if($LastUsed -gt $Threshold)
  {
    # Resolve user profile SID to account name
    $Account = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $UserProfile.SID).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    if($?)
    {
      # Add to Administrators group
      net localgroup administrators $Account.Value /add
    }
  }
}
net localgroup administrators “domain users” /delete
exit
```

Comment: Please post the script itself, might be doing something that's prone to fail under certain conditions

Comment: Ok, I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself - the only contentious part was the .net stuff at the beginning so I tried to comment that part out:

```
    # Launches elevated PS session if possible.
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}
```

and that worked... I assume it was .NET issues on the machines that were failing to execute this properly, thank you for looking at this.